# Need to run a 75mmx30mm 12v .24a blower for 10 sec

Tags: dc, 12v

Hey I am very new so I appreciate any help here I am trying to run this small blower off a computer or 3D printer.  it’s a 75mmx30mm 12v .24A  I need to have it turn on and run for anywhere from 6-8 sec by push of a button and then shut off also would prefer it to run off a small battery possibly and 18650 can anyone advise me I am an ac tech and trying to expand my knowledge thanks again

Comment: Would it be OK if you have to hold the button to keep it on, and it turns off when you let go? That would make it a lot easier to design.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so clear how familiar you are with circuits,
 but the following should give you a good head start:

**How it works:**

The \$R_4\$ represents your load, and upon closing \$SW2\$ the lower side switch \$M_1\$'s gate is pulled up to \$7.5V\$ through the reference voltage provided by the zener diode. At this point your blower is up and running.

*Note that the push-pull button must be held long enough to charge the capacitor \$C_T\$, which should not be longer than a few miliseconds (\$\approx 15ms\$). So, you shouldn't expect any problems with that*

Since \$SW2\$ will be open and block the current flow back to the supply, the capacitor \$C_T\$ is forced to discharge through \$R_T\$. And the time required to turn off the transistor \$M_1\$ and consequently the load is given approximately by:

$$t=-R_T\cdot C_T\ \ln(\frac{V_{th}}{V_Z})\approx-1M\Omega\cdot 4.7\mu F\ \ln(\frac{2V}{7.5V})=6.2s$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fefQXG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>